# mini-css-extract-plugin Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using mini-css-extract-plugin that will perform the extraction of all the CSS code This plugin will create the css file to take to production, when doing the build it gives me 2 errors

> ```
> ERROR in ./src/index.scss
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
>     at Object.loader (C:\Users\admin\Documents\nginx\Frontend\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:20:27)
>     at C:\Users\admin\Documents\nginx\Frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
>     at C:\Users\admin\Documents\nginx\Frontend\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
>     at C:\Users\admin\Documents\nginx\Frontend\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
>  @ ./src/index.jsx 5:0-22
>  @ multi @babel/polyfill ./src/index.jsx
>
> ERROR in ./src/vendor/perfect-scrollbar.css
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
>     at Object.loader (C:\Users\admin\Documents\nginx\Frontend\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:20:27)
>     at C:\Users\admin\Documents\nginx\Frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
>     at C:\Users\admin\Documents\nginx\Frontend\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
>     at C:\Users\admin\Documents\nginx\Frontend\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
>  @ ./src/ui/components/sidebar/SidebarNav.jsx 11:0-47
>  @ ./src/ui/components/sidebar/Sidebar.jsx
>  @ ./src/layouts/Dashboard.jsx
>  @ ./src/routes.js
>  @ ./src/index.jsx
>  @ multi @babel/polyfill ./src/index.jsx
> Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!src/index.scss:
>     Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
>     [0] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.scss 254 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
>
>     ERROR in ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.scss)
>     Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>     TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
>         at Object.loader (C:\Users\admin\Documents\nginxgereci\Frontend\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:20:27)
> Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!src/vendor/perfect-scrollbar.css:
>     Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
>     [0] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/vendor/perfect-scrollbar.css 254 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]     
>
>     ERROR in ./src/vendor/perfect-scrollbar.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/vendor/perfect-scrollbar.css)    
>     Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>     TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
>         at Object.loader (C:\Users\admin\Documents\nginxgereci\Frontend\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:20:27)
> ```

This would be my web package that contains the configuration of the mini-css-extract-plugin.

> ```
> var path = require('path');
> const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
> const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
> const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
> require("@babel/polyfill");
>
> // DEVELOPMENT
> module.exports = {
>   mode: 'development',
>   entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/index.jsx"],
>   output: {
>       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
>       filename: 'main.js'
>   },
>   module: {
>       rules: [
>       {
>           test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
>            exclude:[/node_modules/],
>           use: {
>               loader: "babel-loader",
>               options: {
>                   presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
>               }
>           }
>       },
>       {
>           test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
>           use: [
>             {
>               loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
>             },
>             'css-loader',
>             'sass-loader',
>           ],
>         },
>         {
>           test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
>           exclude:[/node_modules/],
>           use: [{
>               loader: 'file-loader',
>               options: {
>                   name: '[name].[ext]',
>                   outputPath: 'fonts/'
>               }
>              }
>           ]
>         }
>      ]
>   },
>   plugins: [
>       new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
>         filename:'main.css' 
>       }),
>       new CopyWebpackPlugin([
>           {from:'src/assets/i18n',to:'i18n'} 
>       ]), 
>   ],
>   resolve: {
>     extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
>   }
> };
>
> // PRODUCTION
> module.exports = {
>     mode: 'production',
>     entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/index.jsx"],
>     output: {
>         path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
>         filename: 'main.js'
>     },
>     module: {
>         rules: [
>         {
>             test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
>             exclude:[/node_modules/, path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/dev')],
>             use: {
>                 loader: "babel-loader",
>                 options: {
>                     presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
>                 }
>             }
>         },
>         {
>             test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
>             exclude:[path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/dev')],
>             use: [
>               {
>                 loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
>               },
>               'css-loader',
>               'sass-loader',
>             ],
>           },
>           {
>             test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
>             exclude:[/node_modules/, path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/dev')],
>             use: [{
>                 loader: 'file-loader',
>                 options: {
>                     name: '[name].[ext]',
>                     outputPath: 'fonts/'
>                 }
>                }
>             ]
>           }
>        ]
>     },
>     plugins: [
>         new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
>           filename:'main.css' 
>         }),
>         new CopyWebpackPlugin([
>             {from:'src/assets/i18n',to:'i18n'} 
>         ]),
>        new CompressionPlugin({
>       filename: "[path].gz[query]",
>       algorithm: "gzip",
>       test: /\.(js|css)$/i,
>     }),
>     ],
>     resolve: {
>       extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
>     }
>   };
> ```

Previously it worked correctly but I only had the index.scss and at the moment of adding the perfect-scrollbar.css and changing the routing of the application I got two errors, I don't know if I should add something else to the web pack since I don't have much knowledge on this topic.

I appreciate any help you can give me.